# Understanding proofs from paper on Game Theory (Price of Anarchy)

Tags: game-theory

I'm trying to distill the arguments in the paper "Worst-Case Equilibria" (http://cgi.di.uoa.gr/~elias/publications/paper-kp09.pdf). But there are some things I do not understand and would appreciate some help.

Theorem 1: The price of anarchy for $m$ links is $\Omega(\log(n)/\log(\log(n)))$. For $m = 2$ links, it is at least $\frac{3}{2}$. (note: number of agents $n$ = $m$)

I understand that the social cost (expected maximum amount of traffic) is equal to the problem of throwing $m$ balls into $m$ bins. The paper states $\Theta(\log m/\log\log m)$.

Now here is the part I don't understand: (a) "Given that the optimal solution has cost 1, the lower bound follows." I just don't understand what this sentence means. Maybe someone could reword it. (b) "For $m = 2$, this gives a lower bound of $\frac{3}{2}$." How do you show this? I've tried plugging in $m =2$ into $(\log m/\log \log m)$ but you don't get $\frac{3}{2}$. How do you show how to arrive at lower bound of $\frac{3}{2}$?

One more question (for now): There is a proof that says the expected cost of $c_i$ for agent $i$ is at most $2 - \frac{1}{m}$. But it seems what they prove is: $c_i \leq \frac{\sum_kw_k}{m} + \frac{m-1}{m}w_i$ (Aside: can't get the summation symbol to work.)

I don't see how to go from $c_i \leq \frac{\sum_kw_k}{m} + \frac{m-1}{m}w_i$ to $2 - \frac{1}{m}$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**a)**

In this setting, the price of anarchy is

$$\frac{\max_{s \in \mathrm{NE}}\mathrm{cost}(s)}{\mathrm{cost}(\mathrm{OPT})},$$

and to show it is $\Omega(\mathrm{something})$ you need both the nominator and the denominator of appropriate order. The nominator bound $\Omega\left(\frac{\log n}{\log \log n}\right)$ is not enough by itself, you need also that the denominator is $O(1)$. So the bound (also) follows from the fact, that $\mathrm{cost}(\mathrm{OPT}) = 1$, and this is what that sentence means.

**b)**

The symbols $\Omega$ and $\Theta$ and $O$ notations describe only the order (see e.g. [Big $O$ notation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation)), so plugging numbers there isn't very meaningful (at least if you have only one variable). The $\frac{3}{2}$ comes from direct calculation, namely throwing $2$ balls into $2$ bins you have maximum of $2$ and $1$ both with probability $\frac{1}{2}$, hence the expected value is $\frac{2}{2} + \frac{1}{2} = \frac{3}{2}$.

I hope this helps $\ddot\smile$

Comment: yes, it does. Hopefully, you'll look at my last question. Also, I'm not sure what "throwing 2 balls into 2 bins you have maximum of 2 and 1 both with probability 1/2" means. What does this sentence mean?

Comment: As for your last question, it is certainly true for $w_i = 1$ or for $m = n$, for arbitrary $w_i$, $m$, $n$ I think you would need to use how the optimal solution looks like. As for meaning of my sentence: I calculate the expected maximum number of balls in a bin when throwing 2 balls into 2 bins. In such setting the maximum number of balls in a bin can have only two values, namely $2$ and $1$, and each of these values happens with probability of $\frac{1}{2}$.

Comment: thanks. However, I need to ask one more really dumb question. I'm not sure I know what you mean by maximum. The maximum number of balls in a bin is 2 and 1. I don't know what that means. The maximum number is 2.

Comment: Let's assume that bins and balls are distinguishable, then you have four cases: $(1 \to 1, 2 \to 1)$, $(1 \to 1, 2 \to 2)$, $(1 \to 2, 2 \to 1)$, $(1 \to 2, 2 \to 2)$. The maximum of balls in the bins is $2$, $1$, $1$, $2$ accordingly. The maximum is by bins per case, not by bins over all the cases.

Comment: Again, thanks. I guess I just need to go over how to calculate the balls and bins problem.

Comment: is there a formula to solve for this small example?

Comment: @user9915 There is a missing context for "formula", "solve" and "small example". You need to explain what would you like to do, I cannot read your mind.

Comment: Okay, here is what I'm after: how can I calculate the expected max number of balls in a case when there are 2 balls and 2 cases?